# What is bind status?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Some Monsters have Skill effects whereby "bind status is reduced by [X] turns". I don't think I've encountered this status effect yet. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [puzzle and dragons wiki](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Bind!_(foe)), which details the Bind! (foe) ability which binds an enemy:

"Bound monsters cannot attack or use skills, and leader skills (buff effects) are temporarily disabled."